# What files does paprefs modify?

Tags: pulse-audio

paprefs configures pulseaudio in some way, ultimately probably by modifying some configuration files, but which ones? I want to know so that I can do the same kind of configuration but manually using my text editor.

Comment: `strace paprefs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paprefs` currently uses GConf, the GNOME 2 settings storage system (via `module-gconf`).

Its backend storage, while technically "just XML", is *not* meant to be edited directly – instead you can use `gconftool-2` or `gconf-editor` to access the settings under `/system/pulseaudio`.

Note however that GConf is deprecated; nearly no other apps use it anymore. For PulseAudio, you should just make equivalent changes directly to your `default.pa`, the pulseaudio startup script:

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/

echo "load-module module-zeroconf-discover" >> ~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment: The latest PulseAudio release has a new GSettings plugin, so the "GConf obsolescence" part is no longer relevant

Comment: it is possible simply to use gsettings or dconf-editor and see the info at the key /org/freedesktop/pulseaudio/module-groups